# clear button is clearing all the values in the body ? update button is add another row with out updating the given value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

here clear button is not working in javascript?

```js
var a = [];
var index = "";
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "none";
function add(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var lastname  = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
document.getElementById("firstname").value = "";
document.getElementById("lastname").value = "";
document.getElementById("age").value = "";
function clear(){
document.getElementById("firstname").value = "";
document.getElementById("lastname").value = "";
document.getElementById("age").value = "";
}
if ((firstname == "" || lastname == "" || age == ""))
{
alert ("Enter all the textbox values");
}else{
var person = {fname:firstname,lname:lastname,ag:age};
if(index != ''|| index ==' ')
{
document.getElementById("add").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "inline";
a[index] = person;
index ='';
}else{
a.push(person);
}
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "none";
add_details();
}
}
function add_details(){
var table = "";
var row = a.length
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++){
table += "<tr>";
table += "<td>"+a[i].fname+"</td>";
table += "<td>"+a[i].lname+"</td>"
table += "<td>"+a[i].ag+"</td>";
table += "<td><button onclick = 'edit("+i+")' id = 'edit'>Edit</button></td>";
table += "<td><button onclick = 'deletedetails("+i+")'id = 'delete'>Delete</button></td>";
table += "</tr>";
}
document.getElementById("arraytable").innerHTML = table;
}
function edit(t){
index = t;
document.getElementById("add").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("firstname").value= a[t].fname;
document.getElementById("lastname").value= a[t].lname;
document.getElementById("age").value= a[t].ag;
add_details();
}
function deletedetails(i){
a.splice(i,1);
add_details();
}
```

```html
<h1>Students Form</h1>
FirstName :<input type = "text" id = "firstname" value = "" required> <br>
LastName  :<input type = "text" id = "lastname"  value = "" required> <br>
Age       :<input type = "number"id="age" value = "" required><br><br>
<button id = "add" onclick = "add()">Add</button>
<button id = "update" onclick = "add()">Update</button>
<button id = "clear"  onclick = "clear()">Clear</button> <br><br>
<table border = "1" >
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
<tbody id = "arraytable"></tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var firstname = "";
var lastname  = "";
var age     = "";
//var gender    = "";
var a = [];
var ind = "";
var newfname = "";
var newlname = "";
var newage   = "";
//var newgender = "";
var table    = "";
function add()
{
if ((firstname == "" || lastname == "" || age == ""))
{
alert ("Enter all the textbox values");
}
//document.getElementById("tbhide").style.display="none";
firstname =document.getElementById("firstname").value;
lastname =document.getElementById("lastname").value;
//gender = document.getElementByName("gender").value;
age = document.getElementById("age").value;
document.getElementById("firstname").value = "" ;
document.getElementById("lastname").value = "";
//document.getElementByName("gender").value = "";
document.getElementById("age").value = "";
var person = {fname:firstname,lname:lastname,ag:age}
if(ind != '')
{
document.getElementById("add").style.display = "none";
b.style.display = "inline";
a[ind] = person;
}else{
a.push(person);
}
adddet();
}
function adddet(){
var table = '';
var rows = a.length;
for( i =0;i<rows; i++){
table+="<tr>";
table+="<td>"+a[i].fname+"</td>";
table+="<td>"+a[i].lname+"</td>";
table+="<td>"+a[i].ag+"</td>";
//table+="<td>"+a[i].gender+"</td>";
table+="<td><button onClick='edit("+i+")'>Edit</button></td>";
table+="<td><button onClick='deleterow("+i+")'>Delete</button></td>";    
table+="<tr>";
}
document.getElementById("arraytable").innerHTML = table; 
}
function edit(i){
ind = i;
document.getElementById("add").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("firstname").value= a[ind].fname;
document.getElementById("lastname").value= a[ind].lname;
document.getElementById("age").value= a[ind].ag;
//document.getElementByName("gender").value = a[ind].gender;
}
function deleterow(i){
a.splice(i,1);
adddet();
}
function clear(){
document.getElementById("firstname").value= "";
document.getElementById("lastname").value="";
document.getElementById("age").value="";
//document.getElementByName("gender").value="";
}
var b = document.getElementById("update");
console.log(b);
b.style.display ="none";
var d = document.getElementById("add");
var e = document.getElementById("tbhide");
//document.getElementById("tbhide").style.display="none";
```

```html
<form>
FirstName : <input type = "text"   id = "firstname" value = "" required> <br>
LastName  : <input type = "text"   id = "lastname"  value = "" required> <br>
age       : <input type = "number" id = "age"    value = ""    required> <br><br>
<!--Male : <input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "male">
Female:<input type="radio" name = "gender" value = "female"><br>-->
<button id = "clear"  onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
</form> 
<button type = "submit" id = "add" onclick = "add()" >Add</button> 
<button id = "update" onclick = "add()" >Update</button> 
<table border = "1" id = "tbhide">
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>Age</th>
<!--<th>Gender</th>-->
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
<tbody id = "arraytable"></tbody>
</table>
```

all properties are working but clear button is not  working . if  i keep form tag also it is not working

```js
var a = [];
var index = "";
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "none";
function add(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var lastname  = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
document.getElementById("firstname").value = "";
document.getElementById("lastname").value = "";
document.getElementById("age").value = "";
function clear(){
document.getElementById("firstname").value = "";
document.getElementById("lastname").value = "";
document.getElementById("age").value = "";
}
if ((firstname == "" || lastname == "" || age == ""))
{
alert ("Enter all the textbox values");
}else{
var person = {fname:firstname,lname:lastname,ag:age};
if(index != ''|| index ==' ')
{
document.getElementById("add").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "inline";
a[index] = person;
index ='';
}else{
a.push(person);
}
document.getElementById("update").style.display = "none";
add_details();
}
}
```

```html
FirstName :<input type = "text" id = "firstname" value = "" required> <br>
LastName  :<input type = "text" id = "lastname"  value = "" required> <br>
Age       :<input type = "number"id="age" value = "" required><br><br>
<button id = "add" onclick = "add()">Add</button>
<button id = "update" onclick = "add()">Update</button>
<button id = "clear"  onclick = "clear()">Clear</button> <br><br>
<table border = "1" >
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
<tbody id = "arraytable"></tbody>
```

clear button is not working if we keep form tag also it is not wroking can any one help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using forloop and index, you can use child/parent relationship to get the element you want to edit or delete etc.. This is not a full answer, rather an example that should hopefully give you an idea of how to achieve what you're wanting to achieve.

```js
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
function add() {
  var table = document.getElementById("dsTable");
    var newRow = table.innerHTML;
    newRow = newRow += "<tr>";
    newRow += "<td>" + "a[i].fname" + "</td>";
    newRow += "<td>" + "a[i].lname" + "</td>";
    newRow += "<td>" + "a[i].ag" + "</td>";
    //table+="<td>"+a[i].gender+"</td>";

    newRow += "<td><button type='submit' id='delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button></td>";
  table.innerHTML = newRow;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
<table id="dsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>header</td>
      <td>header</td>
      <td>header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @vyjayanthihanchate one option is to use `contenteditable="true"`, to make your cells editable. `<td contenteditable='true'>blabla</td>`. This will allow users to change the content of the table by simply clicking the cell. You can still have an edit button, but the edit button will simply set the focus on the cell, to make it obvious for the users that the cells are editable: `cell.focus()`;

Answer (score 0):

In your add() function you can add a conditon that check what's action was executed.

```
function add(flag) {
   ....
   ....
   if(!flag) {
      adddet();
   } else {             
      document.getElementById("fn"+ind).innerHTML = a[ind].fname;
      document.getElementById("ln"+ind).innerHTML = a[ind].lname;
      document.getElementById("ag"+ind).innerHTML = a[ind].ag;           
   }       
 }
```

In your adddet() function you can give id's our td's to access the values of row by id.

```
 function adddet(){ 
    ...
    ...
    table+="<td id='fn"+i+"'>"+a[i].fname+"</td>";
    table+="<td id='ln"+i+"'>"+a[i].lname+"</td>";
    table+="<td id='ag"+i+"'>"+a[i].ag+"</td>";
    ...
    ...
 }
```

In your html, pass as argument the flag that will say if the action is 
 add or update.

```
<button type = "submit" id = "add" onclick = "add(false)" >Add</button> 
<button id = "update" onclick = "add(true)" >Update</button>
```

I hope this useful for you !

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt but can  u please keep the code in my program ani send me because i am new to javascript this is my first program so please help